# Alternative way of querying through a models' method field

Tags: python, django

I have this model about Invoices which has a property method which refers to another model in order to get the cancelation date of the invoice, like so:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    # (...)

    @property
    def cancel_date(self):
        if self.canceled:
            return self.records.filter(change_type = 'cancel').first().date
        else:
            return None
```

And in one of my views, i need to query every invoice that has been canceled after `max_date` or hasn't been canceled at all.

Like so:

```
def ExampleView(request):
    # (...)

    qs = Invoice.objects

    if r.get('maxDate'):
        max_date = datetime.strptime(r.get('maxDate'), r'%Y-%m-%d')
        ids = list(map(lambda i: i.pk, filter(lambda i: (i.cancel_date == None) or (i.cancel_date > max_date), qs)))
        qs = qs.filter(pk__in = ids) #Error -> django.db.utils.OperationalError: too many SQL variables
```

However, `ids` might give me a huge list of ids which causes the error `too many SQL variables`.

What's the smartest approach here?

**EDIT:**
I'm looking for a solution that does not involve adding `cancel_date` as a model field since `invoice.records` refers to another model where we store every date attribute of the invoice

Like so:

```
class InvoiceRecord(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name = 'records', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    change_type = models.CharField(max_length = 32) # Multiple choices field
```

And every invoice might have more than one same date attribute. For example, one invoice might have two cancelation dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate a [Subquery() expression [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) which will give you the date to do this:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Q, Subquery

def ExampleView(request):
    # (...)
    
    qs = Invoice.objects.annotate(
        cancel_date=Subquery(
            InvoiceRecords.objects.filter(invoice=OuterRef("pk")).values('date')[:1]
        )
    )
    if r.get('maxDate'):
        max_date = datetime.strptime(r.get('maxDate'), r'%Y-%m-%d')
        qs = qs.filter(Q(cancel_date__isnull=True) | Q(cancel_date__gt=max_date))
```

Comment: That's exacly what i was looking for. Thanks for the link, the annotate method will surely come in handy in the future

Answer (score 0):

I would set `cancel_date` as database field when you set cancel flag. Then you can use single query:

```py
qs = Invoice.objects.filter(Q(cancel_date__isnull=True) | Q(cancel_date__gt=max_date))
```

It's say `cancel_date` is NULL or greater than `max_date`

Not sure about your property `cancel_date`. It will return first record with `change_type='cancel'` which can be (don't know your code flow) other record then you call that property on.

Comment: Hi @zelenyjan, we've thought about that, the problem is that besides `cancel_date` we also have `due_date` `passed_date` .. and so on.. Basically there are a lot of "date propertys" for each invoice and sometimes one invoice might have more than one date for that field. So in database terms we concluded that it should be better to have another model where we save Invoice - Type of date (cancel, passed, due.. etc) - Date itself.

Yes, with your approach it would be easier i agree maybe. But im trying to look for a solution not involving remodeling the db as of now.. Thanks :)